# frequency or proportion plot by date or week with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, frequency

I am an epidemiologist and I am quite new to R. I have a simple vaccination data in long format which looks like:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),date=c("01/12/2020","02/12/2020","03/12/2020","04/12/2020",
"01/31/2020","03/12/2020","04/05/2020","02/12/2020","04/12/2020","05/12/2020","01/12/2020"),vac_date=c("","02/02/2020","","04/02/2020","","","04/01/2020","","04/01/2020","05/01/2020",""),dose=c('',1,'',2,'','',1,'',1,2,''))
```

id: patient's identification
date: survey date
vac_date: vaccination date
dose: indicating the vaccination dose

I am really having trouble creating the frequency line plot in my mind. I tried

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = vac_date)) + geom_line()
```

The dates and counts of vaccination are confusing. I would like to compute 2 plots:

1. frequency or proportion plot by date or week regardless of dose
2. frequency or proportion plot by date or week by dose (overlay)
   as shown in the following pic

https://imgur.com/KEoV4cR

Might someone please provide some help on getting the above plots? Thanks.

Comment: One reason your plot does not work is that you have set the x-axis to be date and the y-axis to be vac_date, meaning your are plotting a date against date.

Furthermore, if you run

`ggplot(data, aes(y = dose, x = date)) + geom_point()`

You can see that the way you have structured your dataframe makes it difficult to plot a line graph. In your dataframe you have multiple rows with the same date. It is a bit difficult to see exactly how you are going to acheive your desired plot with the example you have provided

Comment: Your sample data doesn't really make sense. Take the person with ID 1. They already had two vaccinations (2nd February and 4th Februrary 2020) by the time of the first survey date of 01/12/2020. Yet on 2nd December they have their first vaccination recorded and then on 4th December the second vaccination is placed in that row. What is that supposed to mean? Why is the second vaccination recorded on that date? I know this is just made-up data, but it has to make sense and be applicable to your real data in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few different problems here.

- The first is that your data is in the wrong format. You cannot use empty strings in a numeric column in R to indicate missing data. That just turns the whole column into a character vector, meaning you cannot perform any maths operations on it. Instead, missing values in numeric or date columns should be labelled as `NA`.
- Secondly, your dates are currently just character strings and need to be converted to actual dates.
- Thirdly, the `date` column appears to be irrelevant here, assuming that the `vacc_date` column is accurate. What we are interested in is the proportion of all participants who were actually vaccinated by a given date. The survey date itself is not needed.

To fix all of this, I would first start by defining a start date and end date over which we want to display our plot. We should also count the number of participants in our data set.

```r
participants <- length(unique(data$id))
start_date <- as.Date('2020-01-01')
end_date <- as.Date('2020-03-01')
```

Now let's tidy up the data, removing the useless `date` column, and the useless rows with no vaccination information in them. We can then convert the `dose` and `vac_date` to the correct format, and calculate what proportion of participants were vaccinated by each date in the dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse) 

plot_df <- data %>%
  select(-date) %>%
  filter(nzchar(vac_date)) %>%
  mutate(vac_date = lubridate::dmy(vac_date)) %>%
  mutate(dose = as.numeric(dose)) %>%
  group_by(dose) %>%
  arrange(dose, vac_date) %>%
  reframe(vac_date = c(start_date, vac_date, end_date),
          vacc = c(0, row_number(), n()) / participants)
```

Now our data looks like this, with a column for the date of vaccination, a column for the percentage of participants who were vaccinated by that date, and a column indicating which dose of the vaccine they had received.

```r
plot_df
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>    dose vac_date    vacc
#>   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 2020-01-01 0    
#> 2     1 2020-01-04 0.333
#> 3     1 2020-01-04 0.667
#> 4     1 2020-02-02 1    
#> 5     1 2020-03-01 1    
#> 6     2 2020-01-01 0    
#> 7     2 2020-01-05 0.333
#> 8     2 2020-02-04 0.667
#> 9     2 2020-03-01 0.667
```

Our plotting code could then look something like this:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(vac_date, vacc)) +
  geom_step(aes(color = factor(dose))) +
  scale_y_continuous('Percent vaccinated', labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_date('Date', date_labels = '%d %b %Y', date_breaks = 'month') +
  scale_color_manual('Dose', values = c('navy', 'orangered')) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

This allows us to see what percentage of participants had their first and second vaccinations at any moment in time.

<sup>Created on 2023-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I learned a lot from it. Can you please help with a further question? In your answer, the variable "participants" is the fixed total number of subjects. In the actual data, some subjects become lost to follow-up, we do have that last-seen date recorded in the data for those subjects. The denominator would change after those dates. What would be the proper way to adjust that "participants" variable? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For getting a week value you can do:

```
#This will turn you vac_date column into a date
data$vac_date <- lubridate::mdy(data$vac_date)
# This will create an integer column with the number of weeks from the first
# recorded vaccination to the date
data$vac_week <-as.integer(floor(difftime(data$vac_date,
                   min(data$vac_date,na.rm = TRUE), units = "weeks")))
```

Then you can plot your density with

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = vac_week, colour = dose)) +
 geom_freqpoly()
```

to see different doses and

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = vac_week)) + geom_freqpoly()
```

for the aggregated plot.

To get a date instead of a week you can replace `vac_week` with `vac_date` when plotting.